# How to fold a class which is declared inside a class in ruby code

Tags: vim

I am using mvim and I would like to fold the class Experiment. How do I do that?

```
class Lab

  def method1
  end

  class Experiment
    def method2
    end
  end # end of class Experiment

end # end of class Lab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to fold a specific number of lines use `zf` and then a motion command. For example, if you wanted to fold all the lines in `class Experiment`, put your cursor onto the line reading `def method2`, and type `zf2j`. `zf` is the fold command, `2` is the number of lines to fold below the current one, and `j` indicates a downward cursor motion. The result will look like this:

```
class Lab

  def method1
  end

  class Experiment
+--------------- 3 lines: def method2 -------------------------

end # end of class Lab
```

You can also use visual line mode to select what you'd like to fold and then type `za` to fold/un-fold.